# What part of speech is a letter?

Tags: parts-of-speech, alphabets

I wanted to know what part of speech a letter might be or I wanted to see if I understand letters. Do people ask this question in this place? Or am I in the place where people would ask this?
I asked this in language-learning because I thought it would be a language question but I think they showed me that it wasn’t a language question.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech): a part of speech is a category of *words*. A letter is not a word, and does not have a part of speech.

Comment: Letters do not exist in speech, so they are no part of speech. Like punctuation, letters are part of _writing_ – you couldn’t assign a comma or a question mark to a part of speech either.

Comment: Unless you mean the names of the letters, in which case they would be proper nouns.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's how I interpreted the question. And I don't think there's any other. (I don't think they're always proper nouns though, as we talk about "an A", "Bs", "the C", etc.)

Comment: If a letter is not a part of speech, what might letters be?

Comment: Or why aren't letters a part of speech?

Comment: Why isn't anyone responding to that?

Comment: May someone answer that?

Comment: @Janus Bags Jacquet I think you could assign punctuation to a part of a speech.

Comment: @user6779864 No. Punctuation does not exist in speech, so the concept of ‘part of speech’ does not apply to it. Obviously the word ‘comma’ is a noun (you can use it in sentences and see easily that it functions like a noun), but an actual comma is not a noun or any other class of word because it’s not a word at all – it’s a purely graphic tool we use to represent various aspects of language. It’s sort of like asking what car part driving on the left side of the road is to a mechanic, or what type of ingredient in a recipe feeling hungry is.

Comment: @Janus Bags Jacquet I think words are also a "graphic tool" too and me asking that is different than asking "what car part driving on the left side of the road is" because a car part is not or does not mean "driving on the left of the road" but a word might be a graphic tool like a punctuation.

Comment: You’re confusing written words with spoken words. Think back ten thousand years, before anyone had invented writing. Punctuation did not exist then. Words did, because people were speaking, and all spoken languages consist (roughly) of a stream of words. Words are inherent to human language; punctuation is not. You can even write language with no punctuation at all (most old Chinese texts have no punctuation, for example) and be understood, but you can neither speak nor write language without words.

Comment: I think I understand some of what you are showing or saying but I think punctuations can go in place or go before or after something like words. But like you said I think it might be a part of writing too. And maybe they or some showed writing or symbols or writing and symbols existed before words too.

Answer (score -1):

There are two answers, depending on what you are asking. First, they are nouns, so they get case, can be subject or object, take determiners etc. If you have a more nuanced theory of POS with subtypes of nouns, it depends on the language and the theory.

The other, which came up in the comments, is about the actual letters, not the names of the graphic symbols. But in addition, linguists now distinguish "letters" and "sounds" (though Rask talked of changes in letters, and Rask was a linguist). If we speak, we make sounds, if we sign, we make "signs" and if we write, we make letters or characters, depending on what language we're writing. Speech is spoken, so there are no letters in speaking. However, "part of speech" is not about speech, despite the name, it is about language, so letters *are* a part of language. But, "part of speech" doesn't refer to all of the entities that make up language, it refers to a very specific categorization of words, in terms of syntactic criteria. Letters are not classified according to any syntactic criteria, so they don't have a "part of speech", nor do language sounds. "Root", a morphological concept, likewise is a *morphological* entity, not a syntactic one, so roots don't have a "part of speech".

Comment: Why did you show or talk about 'root'?

Comment: Do you understand what a root is, and do you understand the relation between word and root? That might help you to understand the connection to part of speech

Comment: I might be wrong about it or I might not know a little what it is but I think a ‘root’ might be the base word of a word or the base form of word or the original form of a word. Is that what ‘root’ is? Or is a ‘root’ the original form of word?